# Real time chat using PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, long-polling

I'm writing a simple "real time" chat using PHP and JS. All works quite fine, but I stumbled into a problem.

I'm storing the messages into a txt file.

Client side I have two ajax requests (getMessages, sendMessage), one to retrieve the (new) messages stored in the txt file, and one to write single messages to the file.

Server side, at intervals of one second, I check if the modification date of the file has changed (a new message has been saved into the file). If there are no new messages, the request is kept in "pending" state (Long Polling technique), othwerise I respond to the Client with the new messages.

What sometime happens, is that if there are messages sent at short time from each other, the Server responds with just the last new message. Some messages (usually just one) are not being sent to the Client, even if they are stored in the txt file.

This is the code I wrote:

getMessages

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close();
$ft = $_GET["ft"];
$file = "chat_messages.txt";
$length = 0;
$filetime = filemtime($file);
if(!($ft == "y" && file_exists($file))){
    while(!file_exists($file) || $filetime == filemtime($file)){
        $length = strlen(file_get_contents($file));
        sleep(1);
        clearstatcache();
    }
}
echo file_get_contents($file, TRUE, NULL, $length); 
?>
```

sendMessage

```
<?php
session_start();
session_write_close();
$file = fopen("chat_messages.txt", "a");
$text = "{ \"nickname\": \"" . $_SESSION["CHATNICKNAME"] . "\", \"date_time\": \"" . date("H:i:s") . "\", \"text\": \"" . rawurlencode($_POST["msg"]) . "\"};";
fwrite($file, $text);
fclose($file);
echo $text;
?>
```

Hope someone can help

Comment: you should really look into databases, text files are not supposed for chats... save user, message and a timestamp.
request with lastChatUpdate Timestamp and fetch the data

Comment: FWIW, this is the wrong hammer for implementing a realtime chat. Are you stuck to this suboptimal approach for some particular reason? If not, write something based on web sockets which relays messages from socket to socket immediately without the crutch of a text file (or even database) in between.

Comment: @Kapsonfire thank you for your advice, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: @deceze thank you for your comment. Actually, there is no particular reason why I used the approach above, I just didn't want to waste too much time on this so I opted for a "simple and fast" solution.

Comment: @tunny your "simple and fast" solution is in fact a complex and slow (to fix and running too) solution. I hardly advice you to rely on websocket for this. It may took a bit longer for you to get it if it's your first time. But you will get it back in issues and complex debugging you will avoid. More than that. If you are not tied to apache/php I suggest you to use nodejs + express + some websocket library like primus ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/primus ). You can build simple project structure with express-generator and then npm install primus and then copy examples from npm's primus page.

Comment: @bitifet thanks for your comment. The project I'm working on is indeed based on Apache/PHP. Also, I'd really like to understand the cause of this issue. I like to write all from scratch in order to learn step by step, someone will certainly relate to this too :). Anyhow I'll probably look into web sockets at a certain point. Thank you again.

Comment: @tunny: The cause is simple: Concurrency. Each time a client makes a request to the server new PHP process is launched to attend that petition. Process scheduling is not deterministic so from the point of view of a given reader, many many writes (from other processes attending other petitions) may happen so you end up with two (and possibily, even hardly, more) new rows written before you actually read the end of the file. If you need to stay in PHP, read about sessions and use it to store that messages and track which clients received which one.

Comment: ...and, if you also need to store them, better use a database assigning an autoincremented id to each one so you can easily make your clients to claim for ALL messages newer than the last one they received.

Comment: @bitifet I thought the issue was due to gross errors or misplaced code and of simple resolution but obviously I was wrong. Thank you a lot for all your support